# VirtualBox - Unable to install Ubuntu as a guest in a Windows10 host

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox

I'm trying to get ubuntu up and running on a virtual machine (dual boot is not an option).
I cannot go with VMWare because I'm using WSL :/

When I start the VM, I get stuck in this screen :
[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89s6P.png)

Here is my setup (a Desktop):

- Motherboard: MSI b450 gaming plus (SVM Mode Enabled)
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 2600X
- Windows 10 Pro v 1809
- VirtualBox v6.0.8 r130520
- Trying to install Ubuntu v18.04.2 (amd64)

I tried starting the VM with the default settings (except for the RAM and video memory that I increased to decent values)
I tried changing different options of the settings yet it changed absolutely nothing.

I searched a lot over the internet of course, even looked for stuck with keyboard=man
=> Thought it was my keyboard (Corsair K70) and tried with 2 different Keyboards and also different USB slots.

What I can say that I tried all my best to find a solution to resolve it magically on my own but it didn't work out.

I hope there is some kind of an Internet angel around that would be able to help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you start it, does it provide  you options something like install ubuntu/ Try ubuntu?

Comment: @Garry thanks for your replying. It doesn't display anything else to me after the Virtualbox VM start screen other than the screenshot I shared.